# Magento Media Browser Not Appearing

Tags: magento

Did an upgrade from 1.5 to 1.6 and now the media browser is not appearing. When I go to a product and try to add some images in the wysiwyg I get the following message when I try to bring it up:

[image: media browser error]

**The log reports:**

```
ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addJs()  in /var/www/domain.net/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 66
 (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in /var/www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 68
```

**Firebug reports:**

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.domain.net/skin/m/1346486879/js/mage/adminhtml/variables.js,/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js,/js/lib/flex.js,/js/lib/FABridge.js,/js/mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js,/js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js,/js/"
```

I checked all the JS files and they all load. The item /js/ at the end appears to be the problem. Looking in the layout main.xml it appears that it might be /js/prototype/window.js

I tried calling /js/prototype/window.js in the template head which did not work. The log error is for a method that adds the JavaScript to the page.

Here is the code that the log is giving errors messages to:

```
/**
 * Add JavaScript file to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addJs($name, $params = "")
{
    $this->addItem('js', $name, $params);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: what you have on line 66 from Head.php??

Comment: probably something wrong with the path. Try write on txt the name of js files that function calling. something like this $file = fopen('js.txt','a+'); fwrite($file,$name.' '.$params."\n"); fclose($file); and execute it. The last one is having problem.

Comment: Have you checked the line which is _calling_ `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addJs()`, but fails to pass argument #1?

Comment: The trouble is that I have no idea where that is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down the module that was the root of the issue. I saw this issue with custom modules so I figured some module was causing this.

First I turned off all my modules with this command:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print | xargs sed -i 's/true/false/g'
```

Then I tracked it down to: Fooman Speedster

Hope this helps someone else who runs into this issue.